# How to View Visio Thumbnail using getpreview.ashx?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is there any way to preview the visio document in Sharepoint Online.

I have tried using the below url

https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/getpreview.ashx?path={pathToTheDocument}

but can't view the preview of visio. Is there any way to preview the visio in SharePoint online?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, I am able to preview visio documents in my end.

Are you unable to open it in the Document library? Is there an error message?

If it is opened in the app, you can set it as the default browser to open in the **Library settings>Advanced settings>Open in the browser**.

[image]

Comment: HI Elsie,

I Need to preview the thumbnail image of the visio, I am able to view the visio document in browser